# get node variable to react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, textfield, child-process

I start an electron app with https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate

I use child_process from node like :

```
function func() {
spawn('powershell.exe', ["ls"], (error, stdout, stderr) => { 
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  log = stdout ;
console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
}
console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
}
);  
}
```

I would like to get stdout (or log) into a react component (in the same js file)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
// node
var spawn  = require('child_process').execFile;

var log;

function func() {
spawn('powershell.exe', ["ls"], (error, stdout, stderr) => { 
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  log = stdout ;
console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
}  
console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
 }
);  
 }

function Minimal() {
const [ShowGithubDialog, setShowGithubDialog] = React.useState(null);
const [GitLocalRepo, setGitLocalRepo] = React.useState(null);
return (
<div>
<Button
  variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    // className={classes.button}
    onClick={() => {
      func();
    }}
  >
    Start
  </Button>
 <TextField
id="filled-multiline-static"
multiline
fullWidth
rows="15"
defaultValue="Welcome"
variant="outlined"
value={log}
inputProps={{
  readOnly: true
  }}
  />
  </div>
  );
 }

 export default Minimal;
```

When I click on button, the command works, I can see the result on console, but Textfield does not display stdout value ( I try also with log).
I doesn't understand, I miss something ?

Comment: For one, you forgot to explain how these two are even remotely related. React code typically runs on the client, so unless you can explain how your component would even be able to talk to Node, the obvious answer here is "the two are entirely unrelated". Is this something you're doing pre-bundling? If so, talk about how your bundling works. At the very least, turn this into a [mcve].

Comment: I update adding how I launch the script. It's a simple buton

Comment: That doesn't help: the code you're showing tells us nothing about how this _actually_ runs. React in the browser doesn't need a Node server to run anywhere, so where is the rest of your [mcve] code? And please, take that request seriously: we have no idea what you're working on or what your code looks like, nor anything else that is in your head but not in the post: update your post to show how this runs, with everything that isn't related to this specific problem stripped away, so presumably that means a very short Node.js script, and a very short React app, and a description of how to run.

Comment: I update with full minimal example (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.

React Components are rendered on the client. They have absolutely zero interaction with the server, unless an API is used. If you wish to log stuff, simply use `console.log(...)` and watch the browser console.

If you must log server-side, then you will need to set up an API which accepts a request from the client, and prints the request body to the console running on the server. This can be accomplished using Express JS:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/log', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Received log request: ", req.body.message);
    res.status(200);
});

app.listen(3001, () => console.log("API running"));
```

And then in your component:

```js
function func() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: { message: 'This will be logged!' }
    });
}
```

*Untested but should work*

Comment: I have to install express ? Can Electron replace it ?

Comment: I Don't need express. I can start my node function (child_process) from my react component (Buton). The only thing I need it's the value of result into another react component. I think I have to create a custom event

Comment: I search a lot and found useRef hook. I will try this

Answer (score 0):

I use IPC and userRef (uncontrolled component) and works as expected !